# Do you need to be in the same region to attack Collossus?

Tags: untagged

In Tiny Epic Defenders 2nd Edition [the text on the Epic Foe Collossus](https://i1.wp.com/geekdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/TED-EpicFoes.jpg?ssl=1) says:

> When a Defender's card is drawn, that Defender is immediately placed inside the Collossus's mouth (only if no Defender is currently inside the Collossus's mouth). A Defender in the mouth on their Turn can only Fight, spending ❤️ instead of .

Does the defender need to be in the same region as the Collossus to be eaten? I interpreted it as no. But when we played, we defeated Collossus relatively easily in one round because we all got eaten and had enough health to do 3 damage in one go.

Also, if you are not eaten, can you still attack Collossus using actions when you are in the same region?

Comment: You could be eaten only if no defender is currently inside the Colossus's mouth tho

Comment: @lamadelray yes but if you all have 3 hp, you do the damage and get spit out immediately.

Comment: That seems kinda weird that it let you hit after beeing eaten

Comment: @LamaDelRay How so? Would you expect the defender to have to skip a turn? It doesn't say that you have to. It does say that while eaten you spent health instead of actions to do damage.

Comment: I checked and yes it does not say skip a turn, but it would make sense thematically hence my surprise !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As I understand it, the Defender can be anywhere. It is placed in the Collossus mouth when its card is drawn, if there is no other Defender in the Collossus mouth.
2. There are no restrictions on attacking the Collossus with other Defenders, the restriction is only on the Defender which is being swallowed.